# ¿Como hacer un insert con un array de inputs que se encuentran en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, php7, laravel-8

espero puedan ayudarme verán estoy trabajando con Laravel 8,
trato de hacer un insert con un array en la base de datos, este array lo obtengo de inputs dentro de  en una tabla:

```
<tr>    
        <td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN1VBE[]" id="LN1E"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN2VBS[]" id="LN2E"></td>      
        <td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN1VSE[]" id="LN1E4"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN2VSS[]" id="LN2E5"></td>
                                
    </tr>
```

A esta tabla le agregue una función con javascript para poder agregar mas filas:

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnNuevoAlineamiento').click(function() {
      agregar();
    });

    $('#btnDeleteAlineamiento').click(function() {
      eliminar(id_fila_selected);
    });

  });

var cont = 0;
var con2 = 0;
var con3 = 0;
var con4 = 0;
var con5 = 0;
var id_fila_selected;

function agregar() {
  cont++;
  con2++;
  con3++;
  con4++;
  var fila = '<tr id="filaUno' + con5 + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN1VBE[]" id="fila' + cont + '"></td><td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN1VBS[]" id="filaDos' + con2 + '"></td><td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN1VSE[]" id="filaTres' + con3 + '"></td><td><input class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="LN2VSS[]" id="filaCuatro' + con4 + '"></td></tr>';
  $('#dataTable > tbody:last-child').append(fila);
}

function seleccionar(id_fila) {
  if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
    $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada')
  } else {
    $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
  }
  id_fila_selected = id_fila;
}

function eliminar(id_fila) {
  $('#' + id_fila).remove();
}

<
/script>
```

Lo puse como array porque la tabla siempre va a tener filas que se agreguen, ahora paso a mostrar mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
     $diag = new pruebasD();
     $diag->arranque_frio = $request->arranque_frio;

     $var = $diag->id;
    
    $dataSet = [];
    if(is_array($request->LN1VBE) && is_array($request->LN2VBS) && is_array($request->LN1VSE) && is_array($request->LN2VSS)){

    foreach ($request->LN1VBE as $LN1) {
        foreach ($request->LN2VBS as $LN2) {
            foreach ($request->LN1VSE as $LV1) {
                foreach ($request->LN2VSS as $LV2) {
      $dataSet[] = [
        'entrada_on' => $LN1,
        'entrada_off' => $LN2,
        'salida_on' => $LV1,
        'salida_off' => $LV2,
        'pruebadiagnostico_id' => $var,
       ];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                                                }
    return ($dataSet);

}
```

Esta es la tabla, la muestro para que vean los datos que estoy enviando al controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado que me arroja el array:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden notar los resultados me los cuatriplica debido a que en el controlador le indico que son 4 foreach pero entonces de que otra forma puedo acomodar para obtener los datos ?

Answer (score 1):

Hola con respecto a tu pregunta creo bastaría con hacer un solo loop, es decir, una sola sentencia **for**, de la siguiente manera:

```
$LN1VBE = $request->LN1VBE;
$LN2VBS = $request->LN2VBS;
$LN1VSE = $request->LN1VSE;
$LN2VSS = $request->LN2VSS;
for($i = 0; $i < count($LN1VBE); $i++) {
   $LN1 = $LN1VBE[$i]["entrada_on"];
   $LN2 = $LN2VBS[$i]["entrada_off"];
   $LV1 = $LN1VSE[$i]["salida_on"];
   $LV2 = $LN2VSS[$i]["salida_off"];
   $dataSet[] = [
    'entrada_on' => $LN1,
    'entrada_off' => $LN2,
    'salida_on' => $LV1,
    'salida_off' => $LV2,
    'pruebadiagnostico_id' => $var,
   ];
                                                    
}
```

entonces de esa manera te ahorras hacer 4 loops y lo reduces a 1 solo porque el índice **$i** siempre será el mismo en todos los array ya que tienen el mismo número de entradas sin importar que una entrada te llegue un valor vacío de igual manera se sigue contando, espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Me marca error en el "as" dentro del for

Comment: Mil disculpas, no me di cuenta, el **for** debería quedar así:
`
for($i = 0; $i < count($LN1VBE); $i++)
`
dentro de las llaves va lo mismo, ya edité mi respuesta de arriba para que quede más claro

Comment: Hola, estuve arreglando otros detalles en mi proyecto que deje al ultimo estos errores, me sirvió tu respuesta pero si le edite unas cosas para que me funcionara, gracias por la ayuda abajo pongo como quedó con los cambios, por si quieres editar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo igual recomendaciones solo cambie algunas cosas como la declaración de variables:

// Obtengo el id del diagnostico
$var = $diag->id;

```
   $dataSet = [];

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->LN1VBE); $i++) {
    $dataSet[] = [
        'entrada_on' => $request->LN1VBE[$i],
        'entrada_off' => $request->LN2VBS[$i],
        'salida_on' => $request->LN1VSE[$i],
        'salida_off' => $request->LN2VSS[$i],
        'pruebadiagnostico_id' => $var
    ];
```

}
DB::table('pruebaregulacion')->insert($dataSet);